# changing php versions in a laravel (valet) app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-valet

i am facing an issue regarding changing php versions in valet/brew. i notice that `phpmyadmin` requires `v7.2.5+` and i have been able to move (down) to `v7.2.34` .

when i now try to move to `v7.3`  using the following commands:

`brew unlink php@7.2 && brew link --overwrite --force php@7.3` i get the following error:

````
Unlinking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.34_5... 221 symlinks removed.
Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.3```
````